# why this simple programm creates an end-of-file on communicatoin channel error

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE a IS  OBJECT
(
    b    integer,
    c     varchar2(10)
);
/
declare
  cursor ca return a is select 1,'e' from dual;
  va a;
begin 
    null;
   for cur in ca
   loop
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('do nothing');
   end loop;
end;
```

> ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
> Process ID: 803778
> Session ID: 64 Serial number: 4181

the loop as only one element and fast nothing is done in the loop.
But I get the error end-of-file communication channel

As @littlefoot said it works fine if I use a record defined in a package or no record at all. I don't know why it doesn't work with an object

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/GSILu77p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you can't do that.

Oracle does not support returning object types from a cursor. Cursors *always* return a rowtype. So to do something similar to what you want, you can define a table which has a column of the object type you're interested in, and then have the cursor return the rowtype of that table - i.e. something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE a IS OBJECT
  (
  b    integer,
  c     varchar2(10)
  );

CREATE TABLE tt
  (t_a   a);

INSERT INTO tt VALUES (a(1, 'e'));

declare
  cursor ca return tt%ROWTYPE is select t_a from tt;

  an_a  a;
begin
  FOR aRow IN ca LOOP
    an_a := aRow.t_a;
  
    dbms_output.put_line('an_a.b='   || an_a.b);
    dbms_output.put_line('an_a.c=''' || an_a.c || '''');
  end loop;
end;
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/GwJ39obI)

Answer (score 1):

You never said what `a` is.

Documentation says that - if you use `return` clause, then it returns `rowtype`.

> **RETURN**: Specifies the datatype of a cursor return value. You can use the %ROWTYPE attribute in the RETURN clause to provide a record type that represents a row in a database table or a row returned by a previously declared cursor. Also, you can use the %TYPE attribute to provide the datatype of a previously declared record.
>
> A cursor body must have a SELECT statement and the same RETURN clause as its corresponding cursor spec. Also, the number, order, and datatypes of select items in the SELECT clause must match the RETURN clause.

> **ROWTYPE**: A record type that represents a row in a database table or a row fetched from a previously declared cursor or cursor variable. Fields in the record and corresponding columns in the row have the same names and datatypes.

So, if your code were like this, it would work:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    type a is record(val1 number, val2 varchar2(10));
  3
  4    cursor ca return a is select 1 ,'e'  from dual;
  5    va a;
  6  begin
  7     for cur in ca
  8     loop
  9         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cur.val1 ||', '|| cur.val2 ||', do nothing');
 10     end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /
1, e, do nothing

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Or, simpler, if you remove the `return` clause from your own code, it would also work:

```
SQL> declare
  2    cursor ca --return a
  3      is select 1,'e' from dual;
  4    va a;
  5  begin
  6     null;
  7     for cur in ca
  8     loop
  9         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('do nothing');
 10     end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /
do nothing

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If you're asking what's the reason of *end-of-file on communication channel*, I wouldn't know.

Comment: I've add the object definition now. If a is record, it works. But a isn object and it doesn't work.